# how to use identity and concatenate it into the other columns of the table?

Tags: db2, identity

If I generate an identity for a table on the column `cust-id`, I want the next column `userid` to be `cust-id+CID`.

E.g. `000000001CID`, `0000000002CID`

What sql do I include for this?

Similarly if I have `00001` in the column `Cust-id` and `abcd` in the column `section`, the 3rd column must have value `00001abcd`

Please let me know the solutions

Comment: **WHAT** database is this for? Show your table structure! What columns and what datatypes are in use?

Comment: db2. |cust-id  | section | unique-id  |          and the values must be   |0001     |abcd     | 0001abcd   |         similarly for nxt row    it   |0002     |aaaa     | 0002aaaa   |        how can we acheive this in the table? unique-id must be concatenated in the table using cust-id and section.   ( DB2  )

Comment: **WHY** do you want to do this?  Multi-part columns are frowned upon in good db-design.  Multi-column keys are considered a better option (your two original columns).  Storing numbers as formatted strings is a quick way into madness - what happens when you get your 10,000th customer?  Why isn't `cust-id` unique on it's own - why do you feel you need a separate "unique" column?  For that matter, why does it even have to be other information concatenated - why not generate a numeric id or some other guid?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a trigger. Something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER A 
 BEFORE INSERT ON TABLE B
 REFERENCING NEW AS N
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
  SET N.userid = N.CUST_ID + N.CID ;
  IF (N.CUST_ID = '00001' AND N.SECTION = 'abcd') THEN
   SET N.THIRD = N.CUST_ID + N.SECTION
  END IF;
 END @
```

By the way, generating values in column shows that your module is not normalize, and sometimes this is a source of errors.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a generated always column in lieu of the trigger?

Comment: Yes. That is another possibility. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-7-3-0-0-9&lang=en generation-expression